# RSS Reader compiling but not displaying

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, rss

My data is parsing xml fine and compiling, however it is not displaying anything. The two boxes ('lb' - listbox and 'ta') are components - i'm not sure if this has anything to do with its failure to display. Not entirely sure how to go about this.

(concept: box on left hand side should display listed xml recipes using a list component, when clicked the feed should be displayed on the right box, which is a dynamic text area).

```
//create an event listener for the listbox, to change data when recipe is selected

lb.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, itemChange);

//function to change data accordingly

function itemChange(e:Event):void
{
  //textbox data to change to selected item in listbox
  ta.text = lb.selectedItem.data;
}

//create a loader to listen for completion upon loading XML function

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

//declare xml variable
var xml:XML;

//function for event onLoaded
function onLoaded(e:Event):void

{
 trace("successfully loaded");
 /*consider  the itemlist as an array, enabling pinpointing data
 through the XML channel (such as description, title etc) to extract
 the data I want to display.*/

 xml = new XML(e.target.data);
 var il:XMLList = xml.channel.items;

/*create a for loop to add data (in this instance the description text
from the channel of the XML file and also to take the title text from 
the XML and display it in the listbox to convey content.*/

for(var i:uint=0; i<il.length(); i++)
{
    lb.addItem({data:il.description.text()[i],
        label:il.title.text()[i]});
}
trace(il);

}

//load the XML file from a URLRequest to the following website.
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.abc.net.au/local/rss/recipes.xml"));
```

the xml file appears to be way too large/not letting me copy+paste, but it can be found via
www.abc.net.au/local/rss/recipes.xml

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the default namespace, like so:

```
function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    trace("successfully loaded");
    /*consider  the itemlist as an array, enabling pinpointing data
    through the XML channel (such as description, title etc) to extract
    the data I want to display.*/

    xml = new XML(e.target.data);

    //Set the default namespace _before_ attempting to parse
    var atom:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
    default xml namespace = atom;

    var il:XMLList = xml.channel.item; //you were attempting to access "items", but what you really want is "item"

    /*create a for loop to add data (in this instance the description text
    from the channel of the XML file and also to take the title text from 
    the XML and display it in the listbox to convey content.*/

    for(var i:uint=0; i<il.length(); i++)
    {
        lb.addItem({data:il.description.text()[i],
        label:il.title.text()[i]});
    }
}
```

Comment: So it turns out it was the proxy blocking the xml feeds. Thanks for the help though @Marcela